# For SSO/SAML login, get displayName from Azure to Google Identity Platform

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml

I use Google Identity Platform and FirebaseUI-Web for login on my website. I have options for password login, Oauth2 Google, OAuth2 Microsoft, and SSO.

With all except SSO, Identity Platform returns a `displayName` so I have the name of the user logging in.  With SSO I do not, and I would like get it there too.

My customer uses Azure AD on its end for SSO.  They added a `displayName` claim like this:

[image]

but I'm still not getting the `displayName` on my side.

At the conclusion of the SSO login process with FirebaseUI-Web, I receive the user's ID token.  I use this to retrieve the user from Identity Platform, and this is the info I receive:

```
{
    'localId': 'xxx', 
    'email': 'user@example.com', 
    'emailVerified': True, 
    'providerUserInfo': [{
        'providerId': 'saml.xxx', 
        'federatedId': 'user@example.com', 
        'email': 'user@example.com', 
        'rawId': 'user@example.com'}], 
    'validSince': '1639441441', 
    'lastLoginAt': '1639441441196', 
    'createdAt': '1639441441196', 
    'lastRefreshAt': '2021-12-14T00:24:01.196Z'
}
```

How can we configure Azure to provide the user's name to Google Identity Platform with SSO/SAML login?

Comment: perhaps it needs the "SAML" namespace instead of the Azure namespace. "urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.241" for user.displayname.
https://www.educause.edu/sites/default/files/eduPerson-201203-draft-01.html#displayName

Comment: @codebrane, tried that but it didn't work.  :(

Comment: @gaefan Does the [`firebase.sign_in_attributes`](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/saml#signing_in_users) claim contain any related information?

Comment: Hi @jccampanero, I'm using FirebaseUI-Web so I don't see `firebase.sign_in_attributes`.  I updated my question to provide some more details, and I also take a closer look at the link you provided to see if that helps.

Comment: How the SAML response looks like?

Comment: How to do does the FirebaseUI-Web synchronizes?  You still have to have a script/way which gets you the information you are getting.

Comment: @JanGaraj, could you clarify your question.  Which request are you referring to as the SAML response?

Comment: You are saying that you are using SAML as SSO protocol. That has SAML request and SAML response when auth is succesfull, which processed by other libraries (Firebase). Use SAML debugger in your favorite browser and you can catch them in convenient way. That will be first step to see if Azure AD really generates `displayName` or not.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Sorry @gaefan, I didn't realize you mentioned the use of FirebaseUI-Web in your question. Then, probably the link I cited will make no sense. I agree with Jan Garaj, try debugging instead the authentication flow in your browser: I had never used the tool he mentioned, but even with the network tab in your the browser developer tool you should be able to see the information interchanged between the different services involved in the process. It is strange that the response you posted actually doesn't contain any profile related attribute. For testing purposes, ...

Comment: have you tried reading other claims that may be presented in the response to see if you can read them? In addition, please, consider review [the following Azure AD example configuration](https://support.templafy.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000861329-How-to-setup-SSO-with-Azure-AD-SAML2), I assume very similar to the one you are trying to achieve. I hope it helps.